# restricting touchesMoved to certain objects

Tags: objective-c

I have 8 tiles laid out in a 3x3 grid with one blank spot. However, the only tiles that can move are the ones that are next to the blank spot.

I have a centerCoordinate method that grabs the center coordinates of whatever tile you touch:

```
- (CGPoint) centerCoordinate: (NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*) event {
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
location = [touch locationInView:self];
centerCoord = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
centerCoord.x += self.frame.size.width/2-location.x;
centerCoord.y += self.frame.size.height/2-location.y;
self.center = centerCoord;

return centerCoord;
}
```

In my touchesMoved method, I thought that adding a simple if check would work to make sure any tiles along a certain x-axis could move:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
if ([self centerCoordinate:touches withEvent:event].x == 374) {
NSLog(@"got here");
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint tileLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
tileLocation.x += self.frame.size.width/2-location.x;
tileLocation.y += self.frame.size.height/2-location.y;
self.center = tileLocation;
NSLog(@"got here2");
}
}
```

When I attempt move tiles, the "got here" and "got here2" both print out but the tiles do not move. If I remove the if statement the tiles can move freely.

Edit: When I changed touches moved to this, I can move the tiles that are not in x = 374. If I move at tile to x = 374, it locks into place after I let go of it.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

NSLog(@"---1---");
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint tileLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
if ([self centerCoordinate:touches withEvent:event].x == 374) {
NSLog(@"---2---");
tileLocation.x += self.frame.size.width/2-location.x;
tileLocation.y += self.frame.size.height/2-location.y;
NSLog(@"---3---");
}
self.center = tileLocation;
NSLog(@"---4---");
}
```

Any ideas of what would be causing this?

Comment: If the tiles x coordinate has to be 374 for this to work how can you move them out of 374? Also, when you were able to move them the NSLog should update while you're moving them, I'm assuming in the first case you only saw gothere/gothere2 in the console once?

Comment: Yeah, that's the probably I was running in to.  I think I may have figured it out though, thanks.